# Python; Convert Matrix to Binarized version (base 2)

Tags: python, math

**Original Question**

(Looking for help with a function to convert integers in a Matrix to a binarized version with base=2.

I have tried to use `numpy.binary_repr` however it will not work for a matrix.

Any advice/functions?

Thanks)

**Amended Question**

The aim here is to create

-500x50 2D array/previously called it a matrix. Randomised between -1 and +1

-Normalise it to be between 0 and 1

-Multiply by 1000 and round

-Binarize the generated 2D Array by getting the base 2 of them, with a fixed 
    size of 10 bits

**Code Below thus far**

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(seed=1)
Weights = np.random.uniform(low=-1.0, high=1.0, size=500*50)

Weights = reshape(Weights,(500,50)) 


print(Weights.shape)

#Normalise the Weights
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
Weights_Norm = scaler.fit_transform(Weights)
#print(Weights_Norm)

#Multiply by 1000 to get integers below 1000
Weights_Norm_1000=Weights_Norm*1000
#print(Weights_Norm_1000)

Weights_Norm_1000R= matrix.round(Weights_Norm_1000,0)
print(Weights_Norm_1000R)

Weight_int=Weights_Norm_1000R.astype(int)

x = np.array(Weight_int)
print(np.array([np.binary_repr(a) for b in x for a in b]).reshape(x.shape))
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you actually using a Numpy matrix, or a normal Numpy array? And what does this have to do with the Requests library?

Comment: Please post some sample code, or at least a small snippet of this "matrix" thing that you are trying to "binarize" (not really a word). There are several ways to represent a matrix in Python, and the solution will be very dependent on which you are using. (Also, there really isn't much math involved in this question either, unless you want to write the integer->binary representation code yourself.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a `numpy` matrix `x`, you can try:

```
np.array([np.binary_repr(a) for b in x for a in b]).reshape(x.shape)
```

For instance:

import numpy as np

```
x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
np.array([np.binary_repr(a) for b in x for a in b]).reshape(x.shape)
#array([['1', '10', '11'],
#       ['100', '101', '110']], dtype='<U3')
```

Comment: That's not a [Numpy matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html#numpy-matrix). OTOH, I suspect that the OP isn't actually using a Numpy matrix.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I interpreted it as a 2D array. If it actually is a `matrix` the above works if you just replace `x` with `np.array(x)`.